# Css, unwanted Horizontal scroll on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I came across a small problem, for some reason I see a huge white gap in the left of the `<html>` tag

I tried to add the HTML and body tag this rules:

`overflow-x: hidden;
 max-width: 100vw;`

It works on desktop view (even if I resize the browser window)
but it didn't help in mobile (it didn't help in mobile view in chrome dev tools).

What can be the problem?
I think it has something to do with it that the site css is mainly using flexbox.

as well I suspect it has something to do with the div marked in red in the picture (which is position fixed but for some reason appears after scrolling down).

This is that div css rule

```
.contact-mobile{
    position: fixed !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    max-width: 100vw;
    background-color: $black;
    opacity: 0.9;

    a{
        min-width: 25%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
        i{
            color: #fff;
        }
        &:hover{
            opacity: 1;
            i{
                color: $black;
            }
            background-color: $green;

        }
    }
}
```

this is the dev site http://davdev.co.il/broker
this is a zoom out of what I see
https://www.screencast.com/t/P7zQwdWySBv

[image]

Comment: try `overflow-y:hidden;` instead of `overflow-x:hidden;` because `overflow-x` is the horizontal scrollbar and `overflow-y` the vertical

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote vertical instead of horizontal, I have an unwanted horizontal gap. I wrote overflow-x:hidden; but I still see the gap in mobile view

Comment: ahh okay makes sence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem come from your iframe position,

Put `top: -5000px` instead of `left: -5000px`, and it will fix the gap on mobile